# Gridview filter dropdownlist

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, filter

So I have VS 2015 project taking data from Oracle database, displaying as `gridview`. The `gridview` table is large, and I want to FILTER (not sort) the data via `dropdownlist` (ddl) OUTSIDE of `gridview`.

(i.e. table with 1500 entries, 15 columns, 1 column (spec) has 4 possible values of (EN098, SA974, AS0900, VX8762). User selects 1 of these values from dropdown list (i.e. EN098), table of 1500 entries now only displays those (i.e. 670)that have EN098 in spec column).

I have tried binding datasource (OrclSrc) to the ddl then link ddl via WHERE statement (where spec = Control [in GUI] `Control = DropDownlist1.Selected`) to `gridview` (the `gridview` is already linked to OrclSrc), using the wizard on GUI side. BUT upon running website, I get blank `dropdownlist` and no `gridview`.

I have followed tutorials and previous SO questions on this, solutions have not assisted in my own problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring `Dropdownlist1 = PARAM1;` and setting `Control=PARAM1` solved the problem